# How can I prevent Chrome from "remembering" the scrollbar position of a container when children are re-expanded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm having trouble with a "feature" of Chrome where it remembers the scrollbar position of a container when it's height is re-expanded to a prior state. This feature is interfering with my application's ability to scroll an expanded item into view.

To reproduce the problem, open Chrome and run the code snippet below (or check it out on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pndalal/pen/ybrBoM) if you prefer)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  body: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: darkslategray;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow-y: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item>input {
  display: none;
}

.item>input:checked+.item-header:before {
  content: '-';
}

.item>input:checked~.item-content {
  display: block;
}

.item .item-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.item .item-header:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '+';
  width: 20px;
}

.item .item-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  color: lightgray;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <label class="item">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span class="item-header">
      Item
    </span>
    <span class="item-content">
      Here is a bunch of content for this item. Lorem ipsum is no fun to use because it doesn't look like English. So I like to type text randomly, straight from the top. It's a nice activity to just let loose every now and then while developing.
    </span>
  </label>

  <label class="item">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span class="item-header">
      Item
    </span>
    <span class="item-content">
      Here is a bunch of content for this item. Lorem ipsum is no fun to use because it doesn't look like English. So I like to type text randomly, straight from the top. It's a nice activity to just let loose every now and then while developing.
    </span>
  </label>

  <label class="item">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span class="item-header">
      Item
    </span>
    <span class="item-content">
      Here is a bunch of content for this item. Lorem ipsum is no fun to use because it doesn't look like English. So I like to type text randomly, straight from the top. It's a nice activity to just let loose every now and then while developing.
    </span>
  </label>

  <label class="item">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span class="item-header">
      Item
    </span>
    <span class="item-content">
      Here is a bunch of content for this item. Lorem ipsum is no fun to use because it doesn't look like English. So I like to type text randomly, straight from the top. It's a nice activity to just let loose every now and then while developing.
    </span>
  </label>

</div>
```

(1)
Scroll to the bottom of the container, so the scrollbar is at the very end.

[image]

(2) Click on the last item to expand its contents. Notice how the view stays anchored in the same place while the item expands vertically. This is the desired behavior.

[image]

(3) Now scroll to the very bottom with the item still expanded.

[image]

(4) Now collapse the expanded item by clicking on it. At this point, the view will look exactly as it did in Step 1.

The trouble I'm having is that Chrome "remembers" the expanded state. Expanding the item now reverts the view to the same state as in Step 3. I'd like to "reset" the scroll position so that it instead behaves as if you were on Step 1.

I tried calculating the difference in offset().top between the item and the container before and after expansion so that I could manually adjust the scrollbar position post-expansion, but Chrome gives me identical offset values both pre and post expansion, so it's definitely doing something weird.

Can any of you brilliant minds find a way to counteract this behavior in Chrome using JavaScript? Thanks!

Comment: When did Chrome start doing this? They recently introduced Scroll Anchoring, intended to improve the user experience on mobile devices. It would also be good to see some actual code here as to how you were getting back.

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2017/04/scroll-anchoring-for-web-developers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a recent bug, then it likely has to do with the roll out of "Scroll Anchoring", Chrome's newest feature intended for Mobile devices.

https://blog.chromium.org/2017/04/scroll-anchoring-for-web-developers.html

Now, before you cry bloody murder, they were nice enough to allow us to opt out of this new behavior. You need to specify the `overflow-anchor` CSS rule.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-anchor/

```
.your-container-which-has-the-scrollbar-in-it {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That was it! You are a hero. Thank you so much.